# PowerShell Group Sort Select

Tags: json, powershell, sort-object, group-object

I'm imply trying to learn a little and struggling with what I thought would be basic Group By, Order By, ... when working with JSON.

Below is one of my attempts

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos' -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json
$response = $response | Sort-Object -property completed, Count
$response = $response | Group-Object -property userId, completed, Count
$response = $response | Select-Object -property name, Count
$response | ft
```

All I'm trying to do is produce a 3 column table: userId, completed, Count ordered by completed and Count, but can't seem to get it quite right.

The results would end up being like

```
userId  completed   Count
5   false   8
10  false   8
1   false   9
8   false   9
7   false   11
2   false   12
9   false   12
3   false   13
4   false   14
6   false   14
4   true    6
6   true    6
3   true    7
2   true    8
9   true    8
7   true    9
1   true    11
8   true    11
5   true    12
10  true    12
```

Could someone help me.  Once I get 1 functional example I should be good to go.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You want to group on `userId` - nothing else:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos' -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json
$groupedByUserId = $response |Group-Object -Property userId
```

This will already give use the correct `Count` property, and the `Name` property will have the `userId` value we're interested in, so all we need to construct is the `completed` count:

```
$groupedWithCounts = $groupedByUserId |Select-Object -Property @{Name='userId';Expression='Name'},@{Name='completed';Expression={@($_.Group |Where-Object completed).Count}},Count
```

At this point we can sort in the desired order (here by `completed` count, then count, then user id):

```
$sortedGroups = $groupedWithCounts |Sort-Object completed,Count,userId
```

Putting it all together:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos' -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json

$groupedByUserId = $response |Group-Object -Property userId
$groupedWithCounts = $groupedByUserId |Select-Object -Property @{Name='userId';Expression='Name'},@{Name='completed';Expression={@($_.Group |Where-Object completed).Count}},Count
$sortedGroups = $groupedWithCounts |Sort-Object completed,Count,userId

$sortedGroups |Format-Table
```

Result:

```
userId completed Count
------ --------- -----
4              6    20
6              6    20
3              7    20
2              8    20
9              8    20
7              9    20
1             11    20
8             11    20
10            12    20
5             12    20
```

---

Much like `Select-Object`, `Sort-Object` accepts more complex property expressions than just property names:

```
PS ~> $groupedWithCounts |Sort-Object @{Expression='completed';Descending=$true},{$_.userId -as [long]}

userId completed Count
------ --------- -----
5             12    20
10            12    20
1             11    20
8             11    20
7              9    20
2              8    20
9              8    20
3              7    20
4              6    20
6              6    20
```